# Evaluate an integral (another)

Tags: calculus

$\displaystyle{\int\limits_0^{\infty}\frac{x}{e^{ax}-1} \,dx} $

I think it requires a special function like Gamma function but i could not determine if it do or not and how to reformulate the integrand to use it

Comment: you need the polylogarithm

Comment: Uh... all you really need is the zeta function...

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Assuming $a>0$,

$$\frac x{e^{ax}-1}=\frac{xe^{-ax}}{1-e^{-ax}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty xe^{-anx}$$

$$\int_0^\infty xe^{-anx}~\mathrm dx=\frac1{a^2n^2}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6$$

Can you fit the pieces together?

Comment: That is one slick geometric series.

Comment: :P Its how one evaluates the integral$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^s}{e^{ax}-1}~\mathrm dx$$If anyone wants to take a look at that one.  (requires the Gamma function if $s\notin\mathbb N$)

Comment: Don't we need some kind of uniform convergence of the sum in order to exchange the integral and sum?

Comment: @Kari Sure, I believe that would work find.